# Cannot boot to OS X using rEFInd

Tags: macos, startup, partition, efi

I have installed rEFInd 0.8.7 on my 2015 13" MBP onto another partition however it does not detect OS X.

Here are my disk partitions:

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            234.6 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s6
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data Linux                   15.1 GB    disk0s4
   5:                  Apple_HFS rEFInd                  423.7 MB   disk0s5
```

`disk0s4` is where I would like to install Linux when I get rEFInd to work, while `disk0s5` is where I have rEFInd installed to by using the command `sudo ./install.sh --alldrivers --ownhfs /dev/disk0s5`.

The issue I am getting is when I boot up it does not show Yosemite 10.3 (I only have accsess to the buttons at the bottom). To boot to OS X I have to reboot and hold the <kbd>option</kbd> key and select `Macintosh HD`.

How would I get rEFInd to detect OS X?

Comment: what OS is on `disk0s4`?  No swap?  No home?  Purely for my edification.

Comment: I can’t remember as I no longer have this setup. Judging by the name, I think it was Ubuntu Linux I was trying to install. I remember triple booting at one point. If not Linux, it was Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit this file:

```
/Volumes/rEFInd/System/Library/CoreServices/refind.conf
```

Add the following text to the end of the above file.

```
scanfor manual,internal,hdbios,external,biosexternal,optical,cd
dont_scan_dirs /System/Library/CoreServices
menuentry "Mac OS X" {
    icon \System\Library\CoreServices\icons\os_mac.png
    volume "Macintosh HD"
    loader \System\Library\CoreServices\boot.efi
    graphics on
}
```